# Database passwords being stored in Web Deploy pubxml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, webdeploy

I have an asp.net MVC application which is using EF code first migrations.

I publish this project to Azure using Web Deploy.

This all works well but one thing I don't like is that the pubxml file created by Web Deploy stores the connection strings it downloads from the Azure Web App configuration.

These connection string contain the sql azure password, and as I have the pubxml files in source control this situation is not ideal:

```
<ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="3" Enabled="True">
  <Destination Path="Data Source=tcp:###.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=###_db;User ID=###;Password=###" Name="Data Source=tcp:###.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=###_db;User Id=###;Password=###" />
  <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
    <Source Path="DBMigration" DbContext="###.Server.Models.DAL.ApplicationDbContext, ###.Server.Models" MigrationConfiguration="###.Server.Migrations.Configuration, ###.Server" Origin="Configuration" />
  </Object>
</ObjectGroup>
```

Is there a way to configure it not to store passwords or a better way to do the deployment while keeping the passwords safe?

Comment: The easy one is to not store pubxml files in source control. Otherwise, put wrong values (placeholders) in the connection strings and other secrets and set the right values with the Azure panel after deployment (you could also automate this part with powershell).

Comment: By default, the password is encrypted and pubxml is not included in source control. See "Configuring the Connection Tab" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed; its a good practice not to store your credentials or pubxml files in source control!

You are trying to protect the credentials from other people so have you considered a Continuous Integration (CI) process? You'll only have to protect access to the CI servers(s) in this case.
On the CI server you can define a build step to use PowerShell to download the pubxml from an external server, Azure blob storage, or store the file on the CI server copy it in place.

That is how I do it and it has been working extremely well. I cannot recommend this enough.  My build process consist of ***TeamCity Build -> Octopus Deploy -> Azure***.

If you create build steps directly in Visual Studio the build steps are stored in the csproj file and the pubxml will be copied to the computer performing the build; your credentials are immediately compromised.